# How to replace a CRLF char from a variable length file in the middle of a string in Unix?

Tags: unix

My sample file is variable length, without any field delimiters. Lines have a minimum of 18 chars length and the 'CRLF' is potentially (not always) between columns 11-15. How do I replace this with a space only when it has a new line char ('CRLF') in the middle (columns 11-15).  I still want to keep true end of record.
Sample data:

Input:

```
1123xxsdfdsfsfdsfdssa
1234ddfxxyff
frrrdds
1123dfdffdfdxxxxxxxxxas
1234ydfyyyzm
knsaaass
1234asdafxxfrrrfrrrsaa
1123werwetrretttrretertre
```

Expected output:

```
1123xxsdfdsfsfdsfdssa
1234ddfxxyfff rrrdds
1123dfdffdfdxxxxxxxxxas
1234ydfyyyzm knsaaass
1234asdafxxfrrrfrrrsaa
1123werwetrretttrretertre
```

What I tried:

```
sed '/^.\{15\}$/!N;s/./ /11' filename
```

But above code just adding space, not removing 'CRLF'

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Andrew: edited the question with expected output and as well added what I tried. Thank you!

Comment: Do all the lines in the file have CRLF line endings?  Or does the CRLF only appear when a line is split; otherwise, the lines have NL (LF) endings?

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, this seems to produce the desired output:

```
$ awk 'length($0) < 18 { getline x; $0 = $0 " " x} { print }' data
1123xxsdfdsfsfdsfdssa
1234ddfxxyff frrrdds
1123dfdffdfdxxxxxxxxxas
1234ydfyyyzm knsaaass
1234asdafxxfrrrfrrrsaa
1123werwetrretttrretertre
$
```

However, if the input contained CRLF line endings, things would not be so happy; it would be best to filter out the CR characters altogether (Unix files don't normally contain CR and certainly do not normally have CRLF line endings).

```
$ tr -d '\r' < data | awk 'length($0) < 18 { getline x; $0 = $0 " " x} { print }'
1123xxsdfdsfsfdsfdssa
1234ddfxxyff frrrdds
1123dfdffdfdxxxxxxxxxas
1234ydfyyyzm knsaaass
1234asdafxxfrrrfrrrsaa
1123werwetrretttrretertre
$
```

If you really need DOS-style CRLF input and output, you probably need to use a program such as `utod` or `unix2dos` (or some other similar tool) to convert from Unix line endings to DOS.